# How to customize axes in Seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, pairplot, pairgrid

I am trying to customize a Seaborn PairGrid with the following:

- use log scale axes
- control axes limits (I want ylims = xlims for all subplots)
- color/line weight control for major/minor gridlines

I think it can be done by just getting the handles(?), but I am not sure how to do that. [This answer is good for JointPlots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439833/seaborn-i-just-want-a-log-scale), but what is the equivalent of `ax = g.ax_joint` for PairGrids?

I'd also would like to be able to add a 1:1 identity line without having to define a function as [the answer here says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122019/how-can-i-plot-identity-lines-on-a-seaborn-pairplot), if possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(10),
                   'y': np.random.rand(10),
                   'z': np.random.rand(10)
                  })

g = sns.PairGrid(df)
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Update: using `axline` to draw a diagonal line touching the borders, as suggested in the comments. This function is new since matplotlib 3.3.0. Note that for accuracy reasons -- with a log log axis -- `axline` still needs a point close to the minimum and another close to the maximum. Those two points also influence the axis limits.)

To access the axes in a 2D way, you can use `g.axes[row, col]`. To loop through the axes, you can use `for ax in g.axes.flat:`.

You can also use the `g.map_...(given_function)` functions. These will call the `given_function` for each of the axes, with as first parameter the data column used for `x` and as second the one for `y`. Optional parameters can be given via `g.map_...(given_function, param1=..., ...)` and will be collected in the `kwargs` dict. Each time the `given_function` is called, the current `ax` will be set (so, it is not an extra parameter). You then can use `plt.plot` to directly plot on the `ax`. Or use `ax = plt.gca()`.

Here is some example code tackling your questions. By drawing the diagonal identity line, the x and y limits will be automatically set equal. Note that by default the limits are all "shared" (with only tick labels at the left and lower subplots).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def update_plot(xdata, ydata, xy_min, xy_max, **kwargs):
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')
    # plt.plot([xy_min, xy_max], [xy_min, xy_max], color='crimson', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
    plt.axline([xy_min, xy_min], [xy_max, xy_max], color='crimson', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
    plt.grid(which='major', color='navy', lw=1, ls=':')
    plt.grid(which='minor', color='navy', lw=0.2, ls=':')

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(10),
                   'y': np.random.rand(10),
                   'z': np.random.rand(10)})
g = sns.PairGrid(df)
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_offdiag(update_plot, xy_min=df.min().min(), xy_max=df.max().max())
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1)  # a bit more room at the left for the labels
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: how would you make [mn, mx] global so that the 1:1 lines go to limits in all subplots?

Comment: does `global_min` need to be passed in update_plot()?

Comment: Nice! PS check out [axline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axline.html) (recently added to matplotlib) for drawing infinite lines of constant slope.